# How to increase size of pointer array when code is running c++

Tags: c++

Let's say I declared a pointer array like this

```
Animal** animalsarr = new Animal*[10];
```

If in this array, x babies were born and I want to resize it to new Animal*[10+x] while it's running, how can I do it?

Comment: you cannot (unless you are ready to add more stars), use a `std::vector` instead

Comment: you probably want a `std::vector<Animal>` or do you really have a reason to use pointers?

Comment: I am definitely more ready than ever to add more stars. Could you please teach me?

Comment: you should not, and no I cannot teach you, I get dizzy with a single star already :P

Comment: You can do it this way:  `Animal** temp = new Animal*[10+x];` then copy the `animalsarr` into `temp`, then `delete[] animalsarr;` then `animalsarr = temp;`.  But that's not a good C++ way of doing things, in general you should not need to do `free/malloc` or `new/delete` or `new[]/delete[]` at all, since there are better (safer, more easily reasoned about, robust with exceptions) ways of doing things.

Comment: @Eljay Sounds like this ain't a comment, mind removing it and adding it as an answer instead?

Comment: Wait  by copying animamlsarr into temp, can I just do animalsarr = temp; ? or do i need to use the for loop?

Answer (score 6):

C++ is created to make developing easier. It has a really nice standard library containing a type called `std::vector` that does exactly what you want:

```
 std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Animal>> v;
 v.push_back(nullptr);
 v.push_back(std::make_unique<Fish>());
 // ...
 std::cout << "Elements in use: " << v.size() << std::endl;
```

Note: `std::vector::resize` allows you to grow/shrink the vector, however, I have the feeling you actually don't need that at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

there are at least two ways:

1. Manually create new array (Animal** animalsarr_2 = new
   Animal*[10+x]);, move all content from existing animalsarr to
   animalsarr_2, then delete animalsarr
2. Use containers which does all these stuff for you. For example std::vector:

`std::vector<Animal*> animalsarr;
animalsarr.resize(10);`

then when needed, just increase vector size:

```
animalsarr.resize(10+x);
```